# Angular Material - open the md-autocomplete

Tags: angular-material

how to open directly the md-autocomplete to see the options even when we have an element who match with one of the option.

template:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
      <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
  </md-form-field>

  <br />

  <md-slide-toggle
    [checked]="stateCtrl.disabled"
    (change)="stateCtrl.disabled ? stateCtrl.enable() : stateCtrl.disable()">
    Disable Input?
  </md-slide-toggle>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the md-min-length attribute,

```
md-min-length="0"
```

If you have a search function, make sure that you return all data.

Comment: Even with the md-min-length="0" when I click in the input I still have just the element who match with the formControl